# Appending polygons to existing feature class in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator, append

I have a shp file with lots of polygons. I would like to create a buffer zone around the first polygon and intersect it (the buffer) with an other feature layer, than store the result in an existing feature class and iterate this process with Iterate Feature Selection (by ID) till the last polygon. The model runs without any error, I see that it creates every buffer, but the final layer contains only the last one.

I would like to use the layer of buffer zones just as a temporary layer and overwrite it in every iteration and just store one feature layer with the intersections of buffers. How can I append the intersections of buffer zones to the final layer without overwrite the previous result?

[image]

Comment: Looks to me like a case for in-line variable substitution for making unique output names.  However, you need Append.  If you include an Append, then you're adding the output to a destination before it gets overwritten.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [Append](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000050000000) tool to add your intersect_result to a feature class.

First, I would create an empty feature class to store your outputs in, then just add the append tool to your model after your Intersect completes.  Make the empty feature class the Target dataset and the intersect_result the input dataset.

You can save yourself some trouble and use the current intersect_result to create the schema of the new feature class.  If you do that, then you can keep the Schema Type as "Test".  If the schema is different between the intersect_result and your new empty feature class, then use "No Test".